# Set.filter works in Jest test

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

Consider this script:

```
const mySet = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
mySet.filter(i => i < 3);
```

In the browser this code throws *mySet.filter is not a function* error.

Yet when this code runs in a Jest test - it works.

Does somebody know why this happens and what should I do if I want my test to detect this bug?

**Edit:**
I know how to fix the code so it does not throw. My question is how do I make the test **throw and fail** on this code.

Thanks!

Comment: do you have a polyfill for that - or is someone else doing that for you? is this in node?

Comment: you could do `console.log(Set.prototype.filter)` to see where its coming from

Comment: It prints [Function: filter]

Comment: Yes, it's node. I don't know where the polyfill is :(

Comment: try looking at your dependencies

Comment: it might be a tall order, but you could also potentially switch to typescript and set it to be in `dom` mode

Comment: It's already in .tsx actually. What does it mean "set it to be in dom mode" ?

Comment: try setting `lib` to `DOM` in your tsconfig

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel for your patience. I tried to add it and it still does not work..

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to finally trace the polyfill. It came from core-js module that running. Now I just need to find a way to override it globally.

Answer (score 0):

There is no filter on the set method:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Why don't you use an array?

For you second question, in jest just check what / why there is a polifyl for filter , and remove it.

Then it will also fail in jest.

Comment: There is only one question: why won't the tests fail :) I don't know where the polyfill is. That is the problem...